# Two Activities in a transactionscope using Workflow 4.0 not working

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have two activities in the sequence which in a transactionscope which has isolationlevel - serailizeable and 1 min timeout. But when I run the workflow its never commiting to the database. both activities commit data to databases. when I debug there is no error with the acitivites.

one similar issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsworkflowfoundation/thread/22fa47c7-65a6-4295-a779-8c5beedd9bcb?prof=required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft confirms that WF 4.0 does not support long running workflows inside transactionscope.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146833/bookmarking-inside-a-transaction-wf4-0) post

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might a problem with the DTC. To check if that is the case you can run the two DB activities without the TransactionScope. If that succeeds try doing one at the time. If that still works and both fail you need to investigate the DTC on both the machine running the workflow and the machine where the database is located.

Comment: I looked into DTC in both the servers its is started and set to automatic. But I found one thing, in my second activity I have a bookmark activity which will persist to the WWF DB and it will keep waiting for the resume bookmark call to close the workflow. is that impacting the transaction. but its not an delay acitivity. I think it should not be a problem. May be this helps in resolving the issue

Comment: Do we have any solution for this? Similar question by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146833/bookmarking-inside-a-transaction-wf4-0