# bookmarking inside a transaction WF4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I am creating long running workflow with will create a Bookmark for the persistance.
When I execute the workflow it is workflow is working like a charm. 
Issue is here when I enclose the entire workflow in transaction scope, it is not completing its execution once it hits `.waitone()` I don't see the execution.

For sure we need the transaction to be present out the workflow. I checked the DTC setting on the DB its ON. I think issue is with bookmarking in WF 4.0 and transaction on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft** confirms that WF 4.0 **does not** support **long running** workflows **inside transactionscope**. (I don't have this documented but we had a call with Microsoft team, they confirmed that its not supported). What could happen if you do this: Workflow pauses or hangs

Its weird that Entire WF 4.0 has issues with transactionscopes(invoked outside workflow project). Even though I say PersistableIdle.unload (which should persist to the database and should unload from the memory) which look likes a simple job. I don't understand why its having issues with transactionscopes.

Answer (score 1):

How much time is you workflow taking to execute. A TransactionScope has a default timeout of 1 minute, if it takes any longer to execute it will abort. And an ACID transaction that lasts 1 minute is normally way to long, it should not last more than a second or 2 as most transactions place locks on resources like databases.

Another thing is you can't persist a workflow in the middle of a transaction. A transaction is an atomic unit and persisting in the middle would mean you are able to restart in the middle and that would very much break the atomic nature of the transaction.

Comment: I have a bookmark in the workflow which will persist it to DB. which make an entry in DB as executing, Workflow will only be complete when I explicitly call the oncomplete event of the workflow which in not part of the transaction.

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand but it certainly sounds like you are pausing the workflow in the middle of the transaction causing that to timeout and fail.

Comment: If it is creating a pause it should not work even without the transaction. It is hanging only when i create the bookmark inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a bookmark within a transaction?

Comment: Transaction is for some Database operation not workflow related but workflow should only be invoked inside a workflow. my data to and out of workflow is important to other database operations inside the same transaction

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you say, but whenever you start a TransactionScope or TransactedReceiveScope, there will be an implicit Persist operation in the Workflow that shall be executed at the end of the scope and before the commit of the transaction.

Comment: Could you post how your WF looks like? Maybe we could understand better the scenario

Comment: We are not using TransactionScope Acitivity it is from system.transaction dll. I am using it from C# Code.

Comment: Aha, so you are calling a WF from some other place where you are using a TransactionScope object. Well, as Maurice said, if you have a long running workflow, you don't want to have such a long running transaction (I wouldn't have anything asynchronous on a transaction). Are you using Receive and Send activities to call the WF?